# SymmetricDS : How to synchronize the raws which before symmetricds installation

Tags: synchronize, symmetricds

I have a database run 4 months already.
It only can synchronize raws after symmetricDS installed.

Is it possible to synchronize raws include data before symmetricds installation.
How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's possible. Take a look at the chapter [Data Reloads](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.6/user-guide/html-single/user-guide.html#resync-data) of SymmetricDS's user guide.